# Подскажите, как в этом случаи отписаться от события использую React Hook - useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

```
 // Пример функции которая несколько раз переключает слайды     
 const loopSlider = () => {
          for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
              setTimeout( () => {
                handleSlideChange(i);
             }, i * 3000);
           }
           
       };

    useEffect(() => {
      loopSlider();
    
     return () => {}
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const loopSlider = (timeOutIds) => {
          for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
              timeOutIds.push(setTimeout( () => {
                handleSlideChange(i);
             }, i * 3000);)
           }           
       };

    useEffect(() => {
      const timeOutIds = [];
      loopSlider(timeOutIds);
    
     return () => {timeOutIds.map(id=>clearTimeout(id)}
    }, [])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!